# ionic: how to allow multiple menus?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ionic-framework

My app uses a navigation menu that allows switching between different pages. And depending on the page there's also a context menu.

I can't figure out how to make these two `IonMenus` coexist.
The goal is to have two `IonMenuButtons` in the page header. One on the left, for the navigation menu. The other on the right for the context menu.

To create a simple example, I set up a blank project with `ionic start` and added [two of the example menus from the docs page](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/menu) next to the router. Now `<App/>` looks like this:

```
const App: React.FC = () => (
  <IonApp>
    {/* */}
    <IonMenu side="start" menuId="first" id='first' contentId="router-outlet">
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar color="primary">
          <IonTitle>Start Menu</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent>
        <IonList>
          <IonItem>Menu Item</IonItem>
        </IonList>
      </IonContent>
    </IonMenu>

    {/* */}
    <IonMenu side="start" menuId="custom" id="custom" contentId="router-outlet">
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar color="tertiary">
          <IonTitle>Custom Menu</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent>
        <IonList>
          <IonItem>Menu Item</IonItem>
        </IonList>
      </IonContent>
    </IonMenu>
    {/* */}
    <IonReactRouter>
      <IonRouterOutlet id="router-outlet">
        <Route path="/home" component={Home} exact={true} />
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/home" />} />
      </IonRouterOutlet>
    </IonReactRouter>
  </IonApp>
);
```

As you can see, the router has only a single route. In the header of that page, I would like to place two `IonMenuButtons`. Since that doesn't work, I'm replacing one of them with a simple button:

```
const Home: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonButtons slot="start">
            {/* <IonMenuButton menu="custom" autoHide={false} /> */}
            <IonButton
              onClick={() => {
                (document.getElementById("custom") as any).open();
              }}
            >
              <IonIcon slot="icon-only" icon={star} />
            </IonButton>
          </IonButtons>
          <IonTitle>Double menu</IonTitle>
          <IonButtons slot="end">
            <IonMenuButton menu="first" autoHide={false} />
          </IonButtons>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>

      <IonContent></IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};
```

Now, this code has a variety of problems:

- it is not possible to have two `IonMenuButtons` in the same header (in Home.tsx). Only one of them is rendered, the second one disappears.
- it is not possible to have two Menus, only the second menu becomes available. In App.tsx I've placed the `Menu` with `menuID` `first` before the `Menu` with `menuID` `custom`. Only this second menu with id `custom` can be opened. Both the IonMenuButton and my hacky workaround button only work when pointing to `custom`. Switching the order in App.tsx makes only `first` work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that each menu needs a unique `side` property. The following code works:

```
<IonMenu side="start" menuId="first" id='first' contentId="router-outlet">
<IonMenu side="end" menuId="custom" id="custom" contentId="router-outlet">
```

When multiple menus have the same "side" property, they override each other. This causes other side effects: An IonMenuButton that refers to a menu that has been overridden disappears.

Let's say you declared your menus like this:

```
<IonMenu side="start" menuId="first" id='first' contentId="router-outlet">
<IonMenu side="start" menuId="custom" id="custom" contentId="router-outlet">
```

and somewhere else you have:

```
<IonToolbar>
  <IonButtons slot="start">
    <IonMenuButton menu="first" autoHide={false} />
  </IonButtons>
  <IonTitle>Double menu</IonTitle>
  <IonButtons slot="end">
    <IonMenuButton menu="custom"></IonMenuButton> //<---- this one just disappears
  </IonButtons>
</IonToolbar>
```